# Application not adding to startup + startup name is always "visual"

Tags: c#, startup

I tried adding my application to startup, if the user chooses that option. I made this code based on multiple answers on stackoverflow:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;  

namespace Clientding
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main()
    { 
         RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

         if (rkApp.GetValue("ItsAnApp") == null)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("This msgbox is to confirm that the code is being run!");
             rkApp.SetValue("ItsAnApp", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

This does add the application to my startup list, but only with the name "Visual" which should somewhere be caused by visual express.
Also, the application doesn't actually show up on startup.

INFO:
I am running windows 8.
When adding to startup, I believe I hear the sound of a connecting device, then after 2 seconds, the disconnecting sound. I am 99% sure that this has to do with the startup program.

Any ideas why this code doesn't work?

Comment: I still need help with this.. I can't figure it out and workarounds (adding the file to the startup folder without editing the registry) give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Check the restriction that denies users to run application on the Windows start:

To restrict users from running specific Windows programs by editing the registry, follow these steps:

- Click Start, and then click Run.
- In the Open box, type regedit, and then click OK.
- Create a DWORD value named DisallowRun. To do so:
- Locate and then click the following registry key:
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
  \Policies\Explorer
- On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
- Type disallowrun, and then press ENTER.
- Double-click the DisallowRun value that you created in the previous
  step.
- Type 1 in the Value data box, and then click OK.
- Create a new
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
  \Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun subkey. To do so:
- Right-click the following registry key, point to New, and then click
  Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
  \Policies\Explorer Type disallowrun, and then press ENTER.
- For each program that you want to prevent users from running, create
  a new string value in the DisallowRun subkey that you created in step

  1. Use consecutive numbers to name the string values (starting with 1), and use the executable file name for the program as the data for
     the string value.

For example, if you want to restrict users from running Microsoft Internet Explorer:
Right-click the following registry key, point to New, and then click String Value:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion \Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun
Type 1, and then press ENTER.
Double-click the 1 value that you created in the previous step.
Type iexplore.exe in the Value data box, and then click OK.
Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

Comment: I did not restrict anything, and I thought that you don't need to unrestrict something when adding a visual .NET application to startup?